# Select sibling before an element in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The DOM looks like this:

```
<body>
<div>A</div>
<div>B</div>
<div>C</div>
<div id="selected">D</div>
<div>E</div>
<div>F</div>
<div>G</div>
</body>
```

Now I can select `<div id="selected">D</div>` using `$("div#selected")`, then how can I select the element before it, which is `<div>C</div>`.

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: If none of the answers helped or you are still facing trouble, let me know so I can help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplest way is using [prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)

```
$("div#selected").prev();
```

According to the docs, `prev()` will

> Get the immediately preceding sibling...

Answer (score 4):

```
.prev();
```

is what you need, see https://api.jquery.com/prev/

Answer (score 2):

To access previous sibling:

```
$("div#selected").prev();
```

To access all previous sibling:

```
$("div#selected").prevAll();
```

To access all previous sibling untill some point,The parenthesis takes tag name, class name, id etc.:

```
$("div#selected").prevUntill();
```

Similarly to get next siblings

```
$("div#selected").next();

$("div#selected").nextAll();

$("div#selected").nextUntill();
```