# JavaScript / jquery get sibling above element

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

I have this part of a DOM.

```html
<div class="users-layer">
    <div class="ct-user" id="ctUser1"></div>
    <div class="ct-user" id="ctUser7"></div>
    <div class="ct-user" id="ctUser4"></div>
    <span class="messsage"></span>
    <div class="ct-user" id="ctUser8"></div>
    <div class="ct-user" id="ctUser3"></div>
</div>
```

I have the message selected, how would I get #ctUser4?
Should it matter, it's for a userscript in Tampermonkey?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30567684/select-sibling-before-an-element-in-jquery

Answer (score 1):

you can use  **previousSibling property** returns the previous node of the specified node, in the same level or u can also use **previousElementSibling property** based on your requirements.

```js
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("message")[0].previousElementSibling.innerHTML;
document.write('Accessing the previous sibling element'+x);
```

```html
<div class="users-layer">
    <div class="ct-user" id="ctUser1"></div>
    <div class="ct-user" id="ctUser7"></div>
    <div class="ct-user" id="ctUser4"> ctUser4 </div>
    <span class="message"></span>
    <div class="ct-user" id="ctUser8"></div>
    <div class="ct-user" id="ctUser3"></div>
</div>
```